# Rowspan in oracle adf

Tags: html-table, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

In Oracle adf, would you please mention replacement of `rowspan` in `af:column` in `af:table`. I like to place a button between 2 columns and that button is vertically placed in one column which is between 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add new column between the existed two columns and add button inside the new column.

--Peddi

Answer (score 0):

Using the `PanelBox` or `panelGroupLayou`t components, change the alignment to horizontal.